# How to setup url mapping for UUID as PathVariable in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have two entry points in my controller:

```
@RestController("users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserManager mUserManager;

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> all(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page) {
        List<User> users = mUserManager.getUsers(page);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserModel> profile(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null);
    }
}
```

I need to the client could get list of all users by URL `../users/` or `../users?page=1` and the user profile by URL `../users/{550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000}/`. But now I have access by URL `../users?id={550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000}` only.
How to make it?
**P.S.** The UUID is fake from Wiki, it is for example just. 
**ADDED**
My stupid mistake is, I was needed to declare my controller as

```
@RequestMapping("users")
@RestController("users")
```

As I got in the `@RestController` annotation, `"users"` is a bean name.

Comment: what's wrong with your code? Your second controller should match your needs. `@PathVariable UUID id` should contain your `/{ID}` and you can pass the ID to your service

Comment: By URL `http://localhost:8080/users/{B550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000}` my server tries to call `all()` instead of `profile()`.

Comment: And what if you try without the "{}" around the uuid un the url ?

Comment: @a.olivier it has same error.

Comment: did you try to change the order of the controller, maybe the controller above is trigged first (only a suggestion)?

Comment: You need @RequestMapping("users") at `class` level

Comment: @jmw5598Thank you very much! I have found it just now, I did by examples so I thought it is a basic URL mapping for my controller.